# My tooth hurts when I drink liquids?

Tags: dentistry, pain

My front tooth was chipped four months ago and I saw a dentist who filled in the chip and It was sensitive before I had the filling. I can't drink any liquid without it hurting. It's not just cold water either. If I drink room temperature, hot, cold etc..it will hurt. Was there nerve damage..?

Answer (score 2):

A root canal treatment is needed here.This kind of pain indicates pulpal damage which can be relieved by root canal treatment.Consult a dentist as soon as possible.
May i know do you have increased pain during night?